# No frills (non-jQuery) type-ahead for dropdowns?

Tags: select, type-ahead

If I have a bare dropdown box, what is the easiest no frills way to add type ahead?

There is nothing complicated or dynamic about the box itself, it just has a lot of options (here, US States).

Essentially I'm wondering if this simple case can be done in a few lines of code if I'm willing to give up on all the other features like AJAX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function typeDropdown(typedStr,ddObj) {
        var index = ddObj.getElementsByTagName("option");
        for(var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
             if(index[i].firstChild.nodeValue.toLowerCase().substring(0,typedStr.length) == typedStr.toLowerCase()) {
                  index[i].selected = true;
                  break;
             }
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <input type="text" name="search" onkeyup="typeDropdown(this.value,this.parentNode.dd);" />
        <select name="dd">
            <option>Your Options</option>
            <option>Here</option>
    </select>
    </form>
</body>
```

It's not as pretty, but I think this is the simplest you can get.